# Uniqueness of solution for transcedental equation on the open set

Tags: transcendental-equations

What is the best way to prove that x=a is the unique solution for the equation
$$\frac{2a}{x} = \exp (2-\frac{2x}{a}) +1$$
for $x>0$ ?
Intermediate Value Theorem does not work since the interval is open. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Let $x=a y$ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider $ay=x>0$

$$\frac{2a}{x} =  e^{2-\frac{2x}{a}} +1\iff \frac{2}{y}-1=e^{2-2y}\iff\frac{2-y}{y}=e^{2-2y}\iff\frac{y}{2-y}=e^{2y-2}$$

Let $f(y)=\frac{y}{2-y}$ and $g(y)=e^{2y-2}$ and observe that

- $f(y)> 0$ for $0<y<2$ and $f(y)<0$ for $y>2$ but $g(y)>0$ thus consider $0<y<2$
- $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)>0$
- $\lim_y\to2^- f(y)=+\infty$ and $g(2)=1$ thus by IVT a solution exists for $0<y<2$
- for unicity use monoticity